# Fe with different charges

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, redox, transition-metals

Taken these reactions:

> \begin{align}
> \ce{2\overset{0}{Fe} + 3Cl2 &-> 2\overset{+3}{Fe}Cl3} \tag{1}\\
> \ce{\overset{0}{Fe} + 2HCl &-> \overset{+2}{Fe}Cl2 + H2} \tag{2}
> \end{align}

Why does $\ce{Fe}$ have +3 charge in the first example and +2 charge in the second?

Comment: Iron can have two different ions which you have correctly identified as Fe +2 and Fe +3. Other elements are capable of this as well. You may find this link useful, http://www.syvum.com/cgi/online/serve.cgi/squizzes/chem/valency3.html

Comment: Related: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/41095/formation-of-ferrous-chloride-or-ferric-chloride

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/34132/how-is-the-oxide-of-iron-fe3o4-possible

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/32996/calculating-valence-of-oxides/33005

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iron exists in the +2 oxidation state (`iron(II)`), also called *ferrous iron*, as well as the +3 oxidation state (`iron(III)`), also called *ferric iron*.  There are sever other oxidation states of iron that are not pertinent to your reactions.

> In your first reaction, the strongly oxidizing $\ce{Cl}$<sub>2</sub>
>   oxidizes the neutral, metallic iron to it's highest stable oxidation
>   state, `iron(III)`.
>
> In your second reaction, $\ce{HCl}$ oxidizes iron to the lower stable
>   oxidation state, `iron(II)`.